# Sample Space Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Is it true that the set of all possible values of a random variable form the sample space?

I think it is false because it is all possible outcomes that form the same space but I wanted to clarify this.

Comment: No, the sample space is where eat a random variable, not the value it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes. For example, if we are flipping a coin the sample space is $\{H, T\}$ where $H$ is heads and $T$ is tails. A random variable is a function from the sample space to the real numbers. For example, we could define the random variable $X$ such that $X(H) = 0$ and $X(T) = 1$. Note there are infinitely many ways that we can make random variables.